Number of ways to place unit cubes such that they form a convex solid
I was thinking about this problem from Stewert and Tall's book on algebraic number theory:

How many different convex solids can be made by joining $n$ unit cubes face to face, so that their vertices coincide, counting two solids as different if and only if they cannot be mapped to each other by rigid motions. What is the result for general $n$?

Here is what I came up with so far:
First I considered the two dimensional case, so considering squares to form a convex plane. To this end I figured the only way we get a convex surface is when we can form rectangle (or square) from the squares. I assert this can be done, for a non-square number $n$, with divisors $d$ in $\frac{\#d}{2}$ ways, where $\#d$ represents the different number of squares, and for a square number $n$ in $\frac{\#d-1}{2}+1$ ways (the reasoning is that the divisors always come in pairs (when $n$ is not a square), and so these pairs multiply exactly to $n$ and are the length of the edges of the rectangle.)
Now for the case we are working with cubes, it gets more complex. We now have convex solids when we have a cuboid, I believe. So we are looking at the number of ways to create a cuboid out of the $n$ cubes. We again have the same result as the 2D case, when we consider all cubes to only "be in 2D", this are all options up to $n=7$, for $n=8$ we can for example also create the $2\times2\times2$ cube. Now, to count all ways to divide a number into $3$ divisors that multiply to $n$, I am somewhat stuck.
Any suggestions on how to tackle this or just the answer would be interesting to see, as its kept me busy for a while!

The way to partition a natural number $d$ into three nonnegative integers (where order matters) is $(d+1)(d+2)/2$.

Perhaps this is useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/916867/715329

@DynamoBlaze I afraid I don’t really get your comment. Does the formula give the number of ways to partition a number $d$ such that does 3 numbers multiply to $d$? Since the formula always yields a fraction and it doesn’t work for some integers I tried, I figured it meant something else, what would that be?

Any reason as to why this got downvoted?

@RobertoRastapopoulos $(d+1)(d+2)/2$ is always an integer. What I was hinting at is if $n=\prod p_i^{d_i}$ then you can partition $d_i$ into three parts, to get the power of $p_i$ in each of the three dimensions of the cuboid.

@DynamoBlaze Oh wow of course, in my head the top of the fraction is always odd, but it is of course always even, my bad. I will look further with this hint, thanks
